# ToolStripSplitButton vs. ToolStripDropDownButton

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, .net-2.0

What is the difference between [ToolStripSplitButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.aspx) and [ToolStripDropDownButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownbutton.aspx)?
(Visual Studio 2008) (Also asked [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/C_Sharp/Q_21842423.html), not on SO).  At first blush, they seem to be largly the same; especially in the designer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Split buttons are regular buttons with a drop-down menu attached to them. If you click a split button on the button part, it acts like a regular button. If you click it on the menu part, a menu drops down. The "back" button on the majority of browsers are this type of button, for example.

Drop-down buttons, when clicked, drop down a menu. They don't have (and shouldn't have) directly associated functionality beyond displaying the drop-down menu. They are like the topmost items in a menu: they don't do anything when clicked other than to show you more items.

Answer (score 6):

quoted from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/9124f43d-cfb8-422d-ba5e-e07e5c4faeb4/)

> Think of a `ToolStripSplitButton` as a
>   regular button joined to a
>   `ToolStripDropDownButton`.
>
> When you click on a
>   `ToolStripDropDownButton` the `Click`
>   event always fires and the drop down
>   list is displayed.
>
> When you click on the button side of
>   the `ToolStripSplitButton` the `Click`
>   event fires but the drop down list is
>   not displayed and if you click on the
>   drop down side of the split button the
>   drop down list is displayed but the
>   `Click` event does not fire.
>
> In Internet Explorer 6 the Mail button
>   acts like a `ToolStripDropDown` button
>   whereas the Edit button acts like a
>   `ToolStripSplitButton` - i.e., if you
>   click on the image it just fires up
>   the editor wheras if you click on the
>   arrow it offers a drop down list of
>   editors.
>
> Visually, the cue when you hover the
>   cursor over the button is that a
>   `ToolStripSplitButton` will show a solid
>   vertical line dividing the image from
>   the drop down arrow (the two sides of
>   the 'split') whereas the
>   `ToolStripDropDown` button will not show
>   a vertical line.

Comment: Almost. When you click the button side of the `ToolStripSplitButton`, the `ButtonClick` event is raised, but not on the dropdown side.  `Click` is raised either way.